# AWS policy for EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

which policy should we take which gives the cost of every instance which are running in ec2 means they can give all the instance price details which are taken by all the instances in ec2 like if 1 have 10 instances in ec2 so it gives cost of 10 instances cost differently

iam policies

not able to find in policies

Comment: Sorry, but your question is quite difficult to understand. Could you please edit your question to more clearly explain what you are seeking? Please include an example if possible.

Comment: for ex in my aws i am using 10 instances so for that i want to attach a policy in IAM then after applying policy i can see all the usage and cost of 10 instances each and if i attach the policy with user so he can easily see and know which instances taking how much cost

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Trusted Advisor (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/trusted-advisor-console-basic/) I'm not sure why you are asking about policies

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple view for a user to see their specific costs.

Billing reports include costs for all services. You can use **tags** on resources to group costs into particular groups (eg project codes or departments).

See: [AWS Cost and Usage Report - AWS Billing and Cost Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-costusage.html)